# C# DateTimePicker time

Tags: c#, parameters, reportviewer, datetimepicker

I have a project that Asks for input from the user (@startdate and @enddate)

Once they select the date they then have to push a button.
After the button is pressed it will run a stored procedure and return results in the report viewer.

The problem is if I select the same day (For example 5/14/2012).

(@startdate and @enddate are both 5/14/12) it will not display any information becuase it is set to 00:00:00.

I would like datetimepicker2 (@enddate) to have the time stamp 23:59:59.

How can I add 23:59:59 as the time for datetimepicker2.value?

Comment: btw, you should add a whole day, just in that rare case when you have a record with a date between 23:59:59.0 - 23:59:59.999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to add time to datetimepicker2 value:

```
DateTime value = datetimepicker2.Value.AddSeconds(86399); //86400 is 24 hours
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1) in c# - but I don't recommend doing that - it looks like you should be modifying your sproc

I'm assuming you doing a BETWEEN in your SQL procedure?

I usually use

```
YourDate >= @StartDate AND YourDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate)
```

This is because when working with timestamps, you need to select the whole of the day (e.g. 5/14/2012 00:00:00 to 5/14/2012 23:59:59, so using this syntax works because it includes all the time between the start of the start date and the end of the end date

Does your sproc work when choosing an end date that is different from the start date, i.e. does it return data for 5/15/2012 if you pick 5/14/2012 -> 5/15/2012??

If not then you may be seeing this issue

Answer (score 1):

The **minimun** value

> '08/21/2011 00:00:00'

The **maximun** value

> '08/21/2011 23:59:59'

**Usage:**

```
   var firstDate = dtpFrom.Value.Date; //  0:00:00
   var secondDate =  dtpTo.Value.Date.AddSeconds(86400 - 1); //23:59:59 - 86400 is 24 hours
   var list = Services.GetListForFilter(firstDate, secondDate);
```